# File Transfer in python using socket

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, ubuntu, file-transfer

Hi I have made a client and a server architecture using sockets in python to transfer files. It works perfectly fine in windows but in ubuntu it doesnt work.In Ubuntu there is no error but the whole file is not being sent. If I try to send a music file of 4mb only 50-60kb gets transferred while in windows even a file of 300mb sends perfectly. Here is my code.

Client-

```
def sendFile(self):
    # ''' Print a language constructed from
    #     the selections made by the user. '''
    # print('%s!' % (self.recipient.displayText()))
    client_socket.send("upload")
    time.sleep(1)
    client_socket.send(self.virtual_os[self.os_box.currentIndex()].title())
    time.sleep(1)
    path = self.recipient.displayText() #inputbox which contains the path of the file
    self.recipient.setText('')
    name = path.split('/')
    name = name[len(name)-1]
    print "Opening file - ",name
    client_socket.send(name)
    time.sleep(1)
    fp = open(path,'rb')
    data = fp.read()
    fp.close()
    size = os.path.getsize(path)
    size = str(size)
    client_socket.send(size)
    time.sleep(1)
    client_socket.send(data)
    print "Data sent successfully"
```

Server-

```
choice = client_socket.recv(1024)
if(choice == "upload"):
    virtual_os = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print virtual_os
    fname = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print "recieved file "+fname
    size = client_socket.recv(1024)
    size = int(size)
    print "The file size is - ",size," bytes"
    size = size*2
    strng = client_socket.recv(size)
    fp = open(fname,'wb')
    fp.write(strng)
    fp.close()
    print "Data Received successfully"
```

Is there a problem with my code or do i have to change something to make it work on Ubuntu?

Comment: Why don't you just use `len(data)` instead of `os.path.getsize()`?

Comment: os.path.getsize() works fine because i print the size and it prints the correct size, but I tried using len(data) also still doesnt work. And the issue is only in Ubuntu. Somehow only a part of the data is sent.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the data is chunked into smaller pieces and sent over the network interface in multiple segments as opposed to all at once.  Basically, you're not getting the entire message before you're closing the network connection.  You need to add something that checks if there's data that has been received (ie. a while loop to check if the size of the data is 0).  I got the following from one of the examples from the official Python page https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example

```
# Echo server program
import socket

HOST = ''
PORT = 50007
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    conn.sendall(data)
conn.close()
```

Comment: I have tried this too! My main concern is if the same code is working on windows why isnt it working on ubuntu?

Comment: Did you use the loopback interface (ie. ``localhost`` or ``127.0.0.1``) in your tests?  There are some intricacies when sending over the loopback, such as "expanding" the buffer to accommodate the data (don't quote me on that though).  In any case, you should use wireshark or tcpdump to see what's happening.  FYI wireshark won't work w/ localhost on Windows.